# c# Web Service Sorting Result

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I am trying to sort this select by vehicle.DateRegistered but its really confusing me and nothing i seem to do works. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
 var lookupValues = vehicles
            .Select(vehicle =>
                new LookupValue()
                {
                    Id = vehicle.Id,
                    Description = vehicle.RegistrationNumber + " " +vehicle.DateRegistered.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy"),
                    Data = Json.GetString(vehicle),
                    Active = true
                });
        return lookupValues;
```

Thanks Austin

Comment: But you don't sort anywhere..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) extension method:

```
var lookupValues = vehicles.OrderBy(v => v.DateRegistered).Select(.....);
```

Comment: Can i use multiple Orderby's as my code currently has .OrderByDescending(v => v.IsDefault);

Comment: Yes, you can use collection.OrderBy(...).ThenBy(...) or ThenByDescending(...)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code - based on `OrderBy Linq` operator

```
lookupValues.OrderBy(a=> a.DateRegistered);
```

Nota : Add DateRegistered in your selector

Or also you can use this

```
var lookupValues = vehicles

                .OrderBy(a => a.DateRegistered) 
                .Select(vehicle =>
                new LookupValue()
                {
                    Id = vehicle.Id,
                    Description = vehicle.RegistrationNumber + " " +vehicle.DateRegistered.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy"),
                    Data = Json.GetString(vehicle),
                    Active = true
                });
        return lookupValues;
```

Nota : you define direction of order : descending  or ascending

Answer (score 1):

```
var lookupValues = vehicles
        .OrderBy(vehicle => vehicle.DateRegistered)
        .Select(vehicle =>
            new LookupValue()
            {
                Id = vehicle.Id,
                Description = vehicle.RegistrationNumber + " " +vehicle.DateRegistered.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy"),
                Data = Json.GetString(vehicle),
                Active = true
            });
    return lookupValues;
```

Comment: Why don't you upvote other answer instead of repeating it after 5 mins?

Comment: There were no answers when I started writing it. I only saw the other answers when I submitted my own. That happens often when the problem is obvious for those who know.

Comment: Yes that happens often but generally not after 5 minutes.

Comment: It's not a long time when you get distracted by something else.